# Update table in for loop SQLAlchemy (flask)

Tags: python-3.x, for-loop, flask, sqlalchemy, flask-sqlalchemy

I'm trying to do the following: loop through a series of items in dict, and add each one in a new row of table.

For some reason, the adding is working fine only for last item of loop. here's a part of my code:

```
    ######
    # Model of interface_traffic table
    class InterfaceTraffic(UserMixin, db.Model):
        id = db.Column(db.Integer, primary_key=True)
        #
        network_device_id = db.Column(db.Integer, db.ForeignKey('network_device.id'))
        #    
        interface = db.Column(db.String(50), index=True, unique=False)
        traffic_in = db.Column(db.String(10), index=True, unique=False, default=0)
        traffic_out = db.Column(db.String(10), index=True, unique=False, default=0)

        def __repr__(self):
            return '<Interfaces Traffic For NetworkDevice ID: {}>'.format(self.network_device_id) 


    ######
    # Object From Models Tables (interface_traffic table)
    interface_traffic = InterfaceTraffic()
    hostname_for_id = NetworkDevice.query.filter_by(hostname=hostname).first()

    # Dict From Method check_interface_traffic(), provided by host Object Instance of Class NetworkElement
    traffic_on_interfaces = host.check_interface_traffic()

    # Populating Database Params
    for interface, traffic in traffic_on_interfaces.items():
        # interface_traffic.network_device_id is a foreign key
        interface_traffic.network_device_id = hostname_for_id.id
        interface_traffic.interface = interface
        interface_traffic.traffic_in = traffic[0]
        interface_traffic.traffic_out = traffic[1]
        db.session.add(interface_traffic)
        # I tryed with commit in each loop, but has the same behavior
        # db.session.commit()

    # I tryed with flush too, but has the same behavior
    # db.session.flush()
    db.session.commit()
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You need to move creating the `InterfaceTraffic()` inside you `for` loop, otherwise it gets overwritten.

```
for interface, traffic in traffic_on_interfaces.items():
    interface_traffic = InterfaceTraffic() #HERE
    interface_traffic.network_device_id = hostname_for_id.id
    interface_traffic.interface = interface
    interface_traffic.traffic_in = traffic[0]
    interface_traffic.traffic_out = traffic[1]
    db.session.add(interface_traffic)
db.session.commit()
```

Comment: Many thanks @PGHE, your answer solved my problem, i'm so newby in dev world, for now i really don't understand so well... Is it that means for each new row i have to instanciate a new object of my table ? Thanks again ...

Comment: Yes, you create a new object for each row.